# Setting up SDL on OS X 10.8

Tags: xcode, macos, opengl, sdl

I am not sure how am I supposed to setup SDL to work with my mac. I have OS X 10.8.

I remember that some time ago on the [SDL page](http://www.libsdl.org/download-1.2.php) there were development libraries for OS X, Win, and Linux. Now the OS X is missing so im guessing I have to get the linux one working?

And I need runtime libraries which are available for OS X.

What do I need to do to get the whole thing up and running in Xcode 4?

Copy the runtime `SDL.framework` to `/Library/Frameworks`, then what?

I would much appreciate the whole step-by-step procedure since I am not most familiar with these things (but I do know a command or two in shell if necessary).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The development libraries contained Xcode project templates, but the templates don't work with Xcode 4. Since the templates don't work with Xcode 4, the development libraries for Mac OS X were removed from the SDL site. Just download the Mac runtime libraries. The following article  shows you how to get SDL working with Xcode 4:

[Using SDL with Xcode 4](http://meandmark.com/blog/2012/01/using-sdl-with-xcode-4/)

Comment: Thanks. I have managed to get it up and running. For anyone else who will attempt it also check out: http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson01/index.php